# How to obtain the MIME content of deeply nested messages using the Graph REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

According to Microsoft's [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message), you can obtain the MIME content of a message with the command:

```
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{MSG_ID}/$value
```

If the message contains an embedded message as attachment, you can get the MIME content of the embedded message with the command:

```
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{MSG_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT_ID}/$value
```

What if the embedded message contains another embedded message and you need the MIME content of that one? I tried things like:

```
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{MSG_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT1_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT2_ID}/$value
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{MSG_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT2_ID}/$value
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{ATTACHMENT1_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT2_ID}/$value
GET /users/{USER_ID}/messages/{MSG_ID}/attachments/{ATTACHMENT1_ID}/message/attachments/{ATTACHMENT2_ID}/$value
```

as well as other things. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to access the MIME content of such deeply nested messages?

Answer (score 0):

If its a nested Message then it should be an ItemAttachment which you have to expand eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/AAM..KAAA=/attachments/"AAM..Wsk="?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item
```

this should expand both the first level Item Attachment and any nested Item attachments and file attachments of the nested ItemAttachment.

AFAIK what you won't get is the Mime Content of the nested attachment you get the expanded Item itself. If you really want that Mime Content of these nested attachments you should be able to grab the Mime content of the parent message which will contain all the attachments and then use a Mime parser like https://www.mimekit.net/ to extract any nested attachments.

Comment: Thank you. I already expanded the attachment; that's how I know the nested message ID. I was hoping for a simple way to fetch the nested message, instead of fetching the parent message and parsing its MIME content myself. It seems rather strange for the Graph API to parse the attachments completely (since it can provide all the details about the nested messages), yet not provide a way to just get the nested message MIME content.